# How do I hide the hand/cursor?

Tags: java, android, teechart

I want to hide the hand (that's the thing in the middle, right?) of my circular gauge. So far, I tried this:

```
myCircularGauge.getHand().setVisible(false);
```

However, that seems to produce a crash when the diagram is painted. How can I successfully hide the hand?

*Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 558*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using? Here using TeeChart Java for Android v3.2012.0808.

You are right that the following seems to crash:

```
getHand().setVisible(false);
```

However, this seems to work fine:

```
getCenter().setVisible(false);
```

We'll investigate what's happening with the Hand.
Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: I've just found the origin of problem when you try to hide the Hand in TeeChart Java for Android. The next maintenance release will include the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try **replace** a cursor as  **gif not visible**.

```
 int[] pixels = new int[16 * 16];

 Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new MemoryImageSource(16, 16, pixels, 0, 16));

 Cursor transparentCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(image, new Point(0, 0), "Transparent");

 // set cursor 
 frame.setCursor(Cursor);
```